# Reactjs How to insert react component into string and then render

Tags: reactjs

How to create a reactjs component that will render the props data with another component.
for example I have a sentence say "Hello guys this is {{name}}. How are you.". Now I want to replace the name with the reactjs component.
when I try to replace the name with the component it shows as [object object].

First Edit:

```
var sentence = "Hello guys this is {{name}}. How are you.";

var tag_values = {'name': 'any Name'}
```

TagBox will take sentence and tag_value as props and replace the tags with the Tag component. and render it

```
var TagBox = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        // replacing the tags with Tag component
        this.props.sentence = this.props.sentence.replace(tags_values['name'], <Tag \>)
        return(
            <div>
                {this.props.sentence} //Issue: This will Print as "Hello guys this is [Object Object]. How are you." 
                // But this should print as "This will Print as Hello guys this is any Name. How are you."
                // After clicking on "any Name" it should be replaced with input.
            </div>
        );
    }
})
```

Tag Component will replace the tag with input box on double click. and again replace input box with data on enter.
This can be done using state.

```
var Tag = React.createClass({})
```

Comment: Can you give some example code? I don't understand why you need a React component to work with strings.

Comment: I am creating a page where user will be provided with a sentence say "Hello guys this is {{name}}. How are you." now when the user will click name he/she will get a input box to enter a name when the name is entered it will be displayed instead of {{name}}. now for every such tags I am creating Tag component which will be add to sentence by tagBox component. and the sentence string can very every time

Comment: Oh I see, that's a better description. Can you add some example code to your question so someone can help? In a gist: the value of the input box should be stored in `state` somewhere, and when the `<input>` is hidden it should be replaced with the value stored in `state.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Okay, so assuming that's a string you have as input, you need to create an array.

```
var parts = str.split(/\{\{|\}\}/g); 
// => ["Hello guys this is ", "name", ". How are you."]
```

The odd items are literal strings, and the even parts are the stuff between the brackets.

Now we'll create a helper function called `mapAlternate`.  Which takes a function to call for odd elements, and a function to call for even elements in our array.

```
function mapAlternate(array, fn1, fn2, thisArg) {
  var fn = fn1, output = [];
  for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++){
    output[i] = fn.call(thisArg, array[i], i, array);
    // toggle between the two functions
    fn = fn === fn1 ? fn2 : fn1;
  }
  return output;
}
```

Now we can do something like this in our component:

```
render: function(){
    var parts = str.split(/\{\{|\}\}/g);


    // render the values in <strong> tags
    var children = mapAlternate(parts, 
        function(x){ return <span>{x}</span>; }, 
        function(x){ return <strong>{x}</strong> });

   return <div>{children}</div>;
}
```

Which gives us: "Hello guys this is **name**. How are you."

Comment: Thanks.. i was messing around and you made it to easy for me.

Answer (score 4):

Have you heard of [React String Replace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-string-replace) ?

Here is a stateless component example:

```
import replace from 'react-string-replace';
const reg = /\{([a-z|A-Z|0-9|\.]+)\}/g;


const OutputComponent = props => {
    var str = 'Hello {name}, this is a "Super" component: {Super}';
    var output = replace(str, reg, prop => props.replacements[prop]);

    return <div>{output}</div>;
}

// later
import Super from './Super.jsx';
const obj = {
    Super: <Super />,
    name: 'John'
}

return <OutputComponent replacements={obj} />;
```

Answer (score 1):

I just fixed this issue with [react-jsx-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-jsx-parser)

Your Example would be:

```
import JsxParser from 'react-jsx-parser'

export default class TagBox extends React.Component {
    render() {
       const sentence = "Hello guys this is <Tag>name</Tag>. How are you." // simply include the component in your string
        return(
            <JsxParser components={{ Tag }} jsx={ sentence } /> // identify the component in your string to inject
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing from above doesn't worked for me unfortunately. Here is a useful stable solution `regexify-string` ([npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/regexify-string))

> npm install --save regexify-string

Works like a charm

```
regexifyString({
        pattern: /\[.*?\]/gim,
        decorator: (match, index) => {
            return (
                <Link
                    to={SOME_ROUTE}
                    onClick={onClick}
                >
                    {match}
                </Link>
            );
        },
        input: 'Some initial string with [link]',
    });
```